# It is possible for python class attribute to make as decorator?

Tags: python, flask, task, celery, python-decorators

Im trying to follow this [Celery Based Background Tasks](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/celery/#celery-based-background-tasks) to create a celery settings for a simple application.

In my **task.py**

```
from celery import Celery

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
                    broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

This method works in the `app.py` of main flask application.

```
from flask import Flask

flask_app = Flask(__name__)
flask_app.config.update(
    CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://localhost:6379',
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://localhost:6379'
)
celery = make_celery(flask_app)


@celery.task()
def add_together(a, b):
    return a + b
```

> My use case is I want to create another module `helpers.py` where I
>   can define a collections of asynchronous classes. To separate
>   celery based methods and make it modular.

What I did is call the `task.py` module to other module `helpers.py` in order to create a class `AsyncMail` to handle email action background work.

```
from task import make_celery

class AsyncMail(object):

    def __init__(self, app):
        """
            :param app: An instance of a flask application.  
        """   

        self.celery = make_celery(app)

    def send(self, msg):
        print(msg)
```

Now how can I access `self.celery` attribute to be a decorator for any method of the class?

```
@celery.task()
def send(self, msg):
    print(msg)
```

If it impossible, what other alternative steps in order to achieved this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you're trying to do. At the time the class is being defined, there is no `self`, much less `self.celery`, to call, so you can't use `@self.celery`. Even if you had some kind of time machine, there could be 38 different `AsyncMail` instances created, and which one's `self.celery` would you want here?

---

Before getting into how you could do what you want, are you sure you *want* to? Do you actually want each `AsyncMail` object to have it own separate Celery? Normally you only have one per app, which is why normally this doesn't come up.

---

If you really wanted to, you could give each instance decorated methods after you have an object to decorate them with. But it's going to be ugly.

```
def __init__(self, app):
    self.celery = make_celery(app)

    # We need to get the function off the class, not the bound method off self
    send = type(self).send

    # Then we decorate it manually—this is all @self.celery.task does
    send = self.celery.task(send)

    # Then we manually bind it as a method
    send = send.__get__(self)

    # And now we can store it as an instance attribute, shadowing the class's
    self.send = send
```

Or, if you prefer to put it all together in one line:

```
    self.send = self.celery.task(type(self).send).__get__(self)
```

---

For Python 2, the "function off the class" is actually an unbound method, and IIRC you have to call `__get__(self, type(self))` to turn it into a bound method at the end, but otherwise it should all be the same.

Comment: does the `def send(self, msg):` here is removed?

Comment: @Shift'NTab No, you have to define it _somewhere_, and the class is as good a place as any. Although if you want to define it locally right here in `__init__`, or in a global function, or anywhere else, that would also work, with minor changes (e.g., you obviously don't need the `send = type(self).send` if it's defined locally rather than on the class).

Comment: Answering your question. Nope i dont want. I realized that it really creates another celery instance everytime it is called when creating instance of `AsyncMail`. Now knowing this way seems like I need to restructure the class and instead of having flask application instance as paramter, I could use the celery instance defined in the app.py to avoid multiple celery members.

Comment: Seems like the code can work if you just insist to use this approach but now that is a real problem and it will lead to more complex error in the future. You answer shed some light. Thanks for giving your insigth